# how to get an element in n-ary trees

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I'm stacked in a problem about n-ary trees. I want to get a pointer of an element, given the root pointer and the name of an element. I tried to write it recursively but I get segmentation faults.

```
Node* findNode(Node* ptr, const string& name)
{   
    if(ptr->getNextSibling() == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(ptr->getFirstChild() == NULL)
       return NULL;

    if(ptr->getName() == name)

            return ptr;     
    else
    {
        findNode(ptr->getNextSibling(), name);
        findNode(ptr->getFirstChild(), name);   
    }   

}
```

And the n-ary tree consists of a pointer to its next child, a pointer to its next siblinng, a pointer to the root and the data.

Comment: You're testing for `if(ptr->getNextSibling() == NULL)` twice. Maybe you meant to test `getFirstChild()`?

Comment: hmmm that's true. But still it does not change anything

Comment: It still won't make the function work correctly, but it should stop the segfaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic binary search looks a bit like this:

```
Node* findNode(Node* ptr, const string& name)
{   
    if(ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(ptr->getName() == name)
        return ptr;     

    Node *pTarget = findNode(ptr->getLeftChild(), name);
    if (pTarget == NULL)
        pTarget = findNode(ptr->getRightChild(), name);   

    return pTarget;  // might be NULL
}
```

An n-ary search might look more like this:

```
Node* findNode(Node* ptr, const string& name)
{   
    if(ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(ptr->getName() == name)
            return ptr;   

    for (Node *pChild=ptr->getFirstChild(); 
         pChild!=NULL; 
         pChild=pChild->getNextSibling())
    {
        Node *pTarget = findNode(pChild, name);
        if (pTarget != NULL)
            return pTarget;
    }

    return NULL;  
}
```

I haven't compiled or tested this, but I think the algorithms are OK (though sub-optimal).

Comment: actually I was trying to change it, but MS Virus scanner kicked off and hung my machine.  I've just rebooted.  The algorithm I've shown would not call getFirstChild() and getNextSibling(), it would call getLeftChild() and getRightChild().  The getFirst/getNext suggests that each node may have multiple (more than 2) children.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding an element in n-ary tree will be like this.**

```
Tr* search(Tr *root, const string& name) //search Element with ID
{
    Tr *element;
    if (!root) return NULL;
    if (root->getname()== name)return root; 
    while (root != NULL)
    {

        if ((element = search(root->child, id)) != NULL)
        {
            return element;
        }
        root = root->sibling; 
    } 
}
```